# How to run edited Spark MLLib code in Cloudera managed cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, cloudera-manager

I have a 3 node cluster managed by Cloudera Manager. I have edited `BlockMatrix.scala` file in the Spark MLLib source code and packaged it using:

> mvn -DskipTests package

command. It has created new jar file. Now I want to run this newly created MLLib jar on my cluster. What is the way to do that?

Comment: Why change in the source code? It would be better to simply extend `BlockMatrix` and add an implicit conversion if you want to add functionality.

Comment: Actually I wanted to check how much time it requires to complete each of the transformations (to check the computation and communication cost) involves in BlockMatrix multiply method.